# Sub to handle all ActiveX Control Changes, vba

Tags: excel, vba, activex

I'm trying to clean up my spaghetti into a single sub that will handle all checkbox change event on a worksheet. It helps me consolidate the changes to one sub for changes when we adjust rates, it looks better, and looks more professional (my hope).

This is the functioning code block that I have copied 15 checkbox change events:

```
Private Sub ChkDetailStnd_Change()
    FastON
    With Me.TxtDetail
        If .Enabled = True Then
            Me.ChkDetailStnd.value = True
            .Enabled = False
            .Locked = False
            .BackStyle = fmBackStyleOpaque
            .BackColor = &HE0E0E0
            .value = 10
        Else
            Me.ChkDetailStnd.value = False
            .Enabled = True
            .Locked = True
            .BackStyle = fmBackStyleTransparent
            .BackColor = &HFFFFFF
        End If
    End With
    FastOFF
End Sub
```

This is what I am trying to get working by cycling through the controls on the worksheet.   I am getting errors in how I refer to the control in the with statement and then changing the checkbox value.

```
Sub SumPgChk(ChkName As String) 
    
    Dim ctrl As OLEObject
    Dim ctrls As OLEObjects
    Dim i As String
    Dim TxtName As String
    Dim dict As New Dictionary
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Summary Page")

   
    dict.Add Key:="TxtB10", item:=15
    dict.Add Key:="TxtB15", item:=15
    dict.Add Key:="TxtB20", item:=15
    dict.Add Key:="TxtB25", item:=15
    dict.Add Key:="TxtB30", item:=15
    dict.Add Key:="TxtB35", item:=15
    dict.Add Key:="TxtB45", item:=15
    dict.Add Key:="TxtB55", item:=15
    dict.Add Key:="TxtAdmin", item:=5
    dict.Add Key:="TxtDetail", item:=10
    dict.Add Key:="TxtDelivery", item:=5
    dict.Add Key:="TxtMarkup", item:=5
    dict.Add Key:="TxtInstall", item:=5
    
    
    For Each ctrl In ws.OLEObjects
        If ctrl.name = ChkName Then
            TxtName = Mid(ChkName, 4, Len(ChkName) - 7)
            TxtName = "Txt" & TxtName
            With ctrls(TxtName)
                If .Enabled = True Then
                    ActiveSheet.OLEObjects(ChkName).Object.value = True
                    .Enabled = False
                    .Locked = False
                    .BackStyle = fmBackStyleOpaque
                    .BackColor = &HE0E0E0
                    .value = dict(TxtName)
                Else
                    ctrl(ChkName).Object.value = False
                     .Enabled = True
                     .Locked = True
                     .BackStyle = fmBackStyleTransparent
                     .BackColor = &HFFFFFF
                End If
            End With
        End If
    Next ctrl
    
    Set dict = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

I've tried addressing the checkboxes a few different ways based on a few forums and Microsoft directly. Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? on what line?

Comment: `ctrls` is not set to anything.  Try `With ws.OLEObjects(TxtName)`   And use `ws` instead of that `ActiveSheet`

Comment: Do I understand it correct that you have a textbox combined with a checkbox. the change event of the checkbox should set the textbox?

Comment: What does your new code for `Private Sub ChkDetailStnd_Change()` look like ?

Comment: @TimWilliams I generally do us ws, I was just trying anything to see if I could get the right syntax for the problem

Comment: @TimWilliams the `private sub ChkDetailStnd_change()` simply calls `Faston`,`SumPgChk(ChkDetailStnd)`, and `FastOFF` in that order. @aldert I am getting an error with changing the `ActiveSheet.OLEObjects(ChkName).Object.value = True` , its referencing a the checkbox but I cannot change the checkbox's value regardless if I am using the shapes collection or the OLEObjects collection. Yes the checkbox change manipulates the checkbox.

Comment: You're passing a control *object*, not its name.

Comment: I still did not get an answer on my question if you always need a combined textbox/checkbox combination. Your solution is not how I would solve it, better is to work with a class and withevents to keep it neat. I am happy to document that solution but than I need to understand the problem correct. What you have here is still a lot of overhead if you need the object to react on different events...

Answer (score 1):

So you want to go with "more professional"

What you can do is create a little class "CheckText" with all the logic of the interaction between the CheckBox and the TextBox.
The class holds a reference to a CheckBox and a TextBox

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents m_chkBox As MSForms.CheckBox
Private WithEvents m_textBox As MSForms.TextBox
```

It has a function to link the sheet objects to the class

```
Public Function Link(chkBox As MSForms.CheckBox, txtBox As MSForms.TextBox)
    Set m_chkBox = chkBox
    Set m_textBox = txtBox
End Function
```

And for sure it holds your change logic on the checkbox.

```
Private Sub m_chkBox_Change()
    
    Debug.Print m_chkBox.Caption

    With m_textBox
        If m_chkBox.Value Then
            'm_chkBox.Value = True
            .Enabled = False
            .Locked = True
            .BackStyle = fmBackStyleOpaque
            .BackColor = &HE0E0E0
            .Value = 10
        Else
            'm_chkBox.Value = False
            .Enabled = True
            .Locked = False
            .BackStyle = fmBackStyleTransparent
            .BackColor = &HFFFFFF
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

To ensure we have linked the text and checkboxes, the last we need is to add the code on workbook open to link all objects. All is held together by a collection of CheckText objects which you can use when enhancing your code base.

```
Option Explicit

Private m_CheckColl As Collection

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Worksheets(1)
    
    Dim oneOle As OLEObject
    Dim oneCheck As MSForms.CheckBox
    Dim txtName As String
    
    Set m_CheckColl = New Collection
    
    For Each oneOle In ws.OLEObjects
        If TypeName(oneOle.Object) = "CheckBox" Then
            Set oneCheck = oneOle.Object
            txtName = Mid(oneOle.Name, 9, Len(oneOle.Name) - 8)
            txtName = "TextBox" & txtName
            
            Dim oneChkTxt As CheckText
            Set oneChkTxt = New CheckText
            oneChkTxt.Link oneCheck, ws.OLEObjects(txtName).Object
            m_CheckColl.Add oneChkTxt
        End If
    
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Now, the beauty is that you have access to all other event of the checkbox and the textbox in the class itself like:

[image]

No extra coding needed and the change events of the individual checkboxes stay empty:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Change()
End Sub
```

If they need to perform special tasks you can do so without polluting the "common base"

Comment: Is this a common to transform the control from activex to msforms? I will try to implement the new class today and get back to you. Thank you in advance. and yes cleaning my code up is much more professional. I only get to code when we need something at the business I work for, so I always start with the verbal diarrhoea method get it working don't specifically worry about overlap in the code. Then once its working and we have the right buy in, I go back document and try to clean up everything into concise code, and build my own common base code that I can take from project to project.

Comment: the activex are msforms objects. We will need to cast them to get back to the properties and events of the objects.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to pass the checkbox *object* to the Sub and not its *name*.

You can do it something like this (I used a simpler control name mapping from checkbox to textbox - eg "ChkDetailStnd1" >> "TxtDetailStnd1":

```vb
Private Sub ChkDetailStnd1_Change()
    SumPgChk ChkDetailStnd1
End Sub

Private Sub ChkDetailStnd2_Click()
    SumPgChk ChkDetailStnd2
End Sub

Private Sub ChkDetailStnd3_Click()
    SumPgChk ChkDetailStnd3
End Sub

Private Sub ChkDetailStnd4_Click()
    SumPgChk ChkDetailStnd4
End Sub

Sub SumPgChk(chk As Object)
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim TxtName As String, txtBox As Object
    
    Set ws = chk.Parent                         'sheet hosting the checkbox
    TxtName = Replace(chk.Name, "Chk", "Txt")   'map to matching textbox name
    
    Set txtBox = CallByName(ws, TxtName, VbGet) 'access a control by its name
    Debug.Print "Got " & txtBox.Name
    
    With txtBox
        .Enabled = chk.Value     'set according to checkbox value
        .Locked = Not .Enabled
        'I may have these back-to-front...
        .BackStyle = IIf(.Enabled, fmBackStyleOpaque, fmBackStyleTransparent)
        .BackColor = IIf(.Enabled, &HE0E0E0, &HFFFFFF)
    
        If .Enabled Then 'setting a value?
            Select Case TxtName
                Case "TxtDetailStnd1", "TxtDetailStnd3"
                    .Value = 10
                Case "TxtDetailStnd2", "TxtDetailStnd4"
                    .Value = 20
            End Select
        Else
            .Value = "" '?
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @tim williams, I am going to try the class implementation that Aldert has suggested and get back you. This is a neat solution too